# Does govendor automatically include transitive dependencies?

Tags: go, dependencies, vendor, govendor

Let's say I add a new dependency X through `govendor add` or `govendor fetch`.  This dependency X has a dependency on Y.

Will govendor automatically pull in those dependencies as well?  Or will I have to do `govendor add Y`.

Does the behavior differ betweeen `add` and `fetch`?

I couldn't find this discussed on any of the documentation here: https://github.com/kardianos/govendor

Or by running `govendor add --help`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`govendor fetch <package_name>` will automatically include transitive dependencies.

`govendor add <package_name>` will not.

However if you run `govendor add +external` (with no package name) it will vendor the dependencies and transitive dependencies that your code relies on, as long as they are checked out on your GOPATH.